# Can't adjust laptop screen brightness on Ubuntu 20.10 equivalent

Tags: gnome, keyboard, brightness, pop-os

I'm dual-booting a laptop (Dell Precision 7550) between Windows 10 and pop!_os 20.10, equivalent to Ubuntu 20.10. I have an issue regarding screen brightness.

The laptop is stuck at a certain mellow screen brightness, and I cannot change it. Pressing the physical keyboard keys to control brightness will make the normal-looking brightness prompt show up on the screen and increase/decrease the slider, depending on which button I press. However, even though the slider changes, the actual screen brightness stays the same. The same problem occurs if I use the Gnome brightness slider from the top right-hand corner of the screen.

Inside `/sys/class/backlight` are two directories: `intel_backlight` and `dell_backlight`. When I attempt to adjust the brightness (via buttons or the Gnome slider), `intel_backlight/brightness` does not change, but the values for `dell_backlight/brightness` **do** change (without the screen brightness adjusting).

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can fix this issue?

**I've already tried**:

- Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` in `/etc/default/grub`.
- Making `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and putting the following inside (apologies, can't get the formatting right):

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

- Looking at the output of `journalctl -b -0|grep light`: all looked normal, except for an error saying "Apr 27 11:10:45 pop-os system76-power[818]: [ERROR] hid_backlight: no system76_acpi::kbd_backlight led" (presumably because the laptop does not have a light-up keyboard).
- Changing the permissions of `/sys/class/brightness` to user instead of root. No effect.

**Workaround:**

The only way I can adjust the screen brightness as all is using `xrandr`: e.g. `xrandr --output eDPI --brightness 0.8`

**Other information:**

Output of `uname -a`:
Linux pop-os 5.11.0-7612-generic #13~1617215757~20.10~97a8d1a-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 1 21:09:17 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output of `sudo lshw -c display`:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU104GLM [Quadro RTX 4000 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:223 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:b4000000-b407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3840x2160 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:172 memory:604a000000-604affffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have in boot messages `Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.`  Try `journalctl -b -0|grep light` and report.  Maybe you find an error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Along with many outputs, including the same `Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight` you got, there was the following error:

`Apr 27 11:10:45 pop-os system76-power[818]: [ERROR] hid_backlight: no system76_acpi::kbd_backlight led`

Any idea what this might mean, or how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: (First a note, you can edit your original question to include any additionally requested or newly discovered information.) What are the full permissions of both \*_backlight files/directories? (I ask because awhile back, I saw a similar backlight issue where the permissions needed to be changed to allow non-root to change the brightness...)

Comment: I used `ls -l` on /sys/class/backlight. Both files had the following permissions:

"lrwxrwxrwx root root".

I tried using `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /sys/class/backlight`, which changed the permissions to myself as non-root, but using the brightness buttons/slider still had no effect except to set screen brightness to maximum.

The only silly way I'm able to adjust brightness at the moment is through the terminal using `xrandr`, e.g. `xrandr --output eDPI --brightness 0.8`.